# how to enable .zip extension in server

Tags: .htaccess, zip, extension-methods, php

I want to enable the `.zip` extension in my server. I added the below code in a `php.ini` file. But the website will take the default `php.ini` file.

```
extension=php_zip.dll
extension=zip.so
```

If I upload it in to the root directory of my website. Is there any way to take the uploaded php.ini instead of default `php.ini` ??

Or is there any other way (`.htaccess`) to enable .zip extension in the server??

Comment: Why not use PECL extension?

Comment: Can you check by adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .zip` in your .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

> If I upload it [the php.ini file] in to the root directory of my website. Is there any way to take the uploaded php.ini instead of default `php.ini`?

You need to contact your hoster which options it offers. By default just uploading a (php.ini) file will place that file in your webroot so it can be downloaded by visitors but it has not influence on your PHP configuration.

> Or is there any other way (`.htaccess`) to enable .zip extension in the server?

No, per `.htaccess` there is no way to enable the .zip extension. The [`extension` PHP ini-directive](http://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.extension) is for *`php.ini`* only.

You need to contact your hoster and discuss the issue, many hosters offer to install extensions for you and also they offer some mechanism to allow you to specify your own php.ini but how that is done depends on the hoster.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line in the file: `C:\xampp\php\ext\PHP.ini`
(can be opened from XAMPP Control Panel => Apache => config)

```
extension=php_zip.dll
```

And then stop and start, XAMPP Apache service worked